# Passing the partially constructed object in pimpl

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I have a class setup that I have converted to use *pimpl*, something like this:

***(outline only, I'm aware this doesn't compile)***

```
struct GAME
{
    unique_ptr<GAME_IMPL> _impl; 

    explicit GAME() : _impl( new GAME_IMPL( *this ) );
    IMAGES getImages() { return _impl._images; }
};

struct GAME_IMPL
{
    IMAGES _images;
    PLAYER _player;

    explicit GAME_IMPL( GAME& game ) : _player( game ) { }
};

struct PLAYER
{
    SPRITE _sprite;

    explicit PLAYER( GAME& game ) { _sprite.load( game.getImages() ); }
};
```

Before I converted to a pimpl pattern, this was fine.
`_sprite.load( game.getImages() )` could access `GAME::_images` because `GAME::_images` instantiates before `GAME::_player`.

However, after converting to pimpl, you can see that `_sprite.load( game.getImages() )` will fail - `PLAYER` cannot access `GAME::_images`, because `GAME::getImages` uses `GAME::_impl`, which is not assigned until after *all* of `GAME_IMPL` has been constructed.

Obviously my example is contrived. But is there some way to allow the `_impl` pointer to be set before or while the `GAME_IMPL` object is still being constructed?

I considered the following:

- Passing `PLAYER` only the necessary elements. This is messy since it involves modifying the API of `PLAYER::PLAYER` every time I adjust `PLAYER`'s fields. Also in practice `PLAYER`'s constructor may end up taking 30 odd parameters.
- Using a two-stage initialisation, e.g. `PLAYER::PLAYER()`, `PLAYER::Load()` - this is even more messy since it means converting references to pointers throughout.
- Passing `PLAYER` `GAME_IMPL` instead - this loses any benefits of using *pimpl* in the first place.

Comment: Just forward declare `PLAYER` and write function definitions after all classes that they rely on - not in class definition.

Comment: No, there is no "way to allow the `_impl` pointer to be set before" the object it's pointing to is fully constructed, by the `new` operator whose result gets assigned to the `_impl` pointer. This is fundamental to C++. C++ simply does not work any other way. You will need to redesign how your classes work, and their mutual relationships, in order to make it fit within this design pattern.

Comment: `GAME_IMPL(GAME& game)` is suspicious IMO.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: OP's problem is not compilation, but access to not initalized pointer, as `this` (from `GAME`) is still in construction. Modified [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5sdbq8dcf) with non empty struct.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm open to alternatives! This is essentially to skirt around using a singleton, but a singleton wouldn't fix the issue either.

Comment: For me, your first alternative is the right way (So `PLAYER(const Images&)`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Aha, I misunderstood "_you can see that `_sprite.load( game.getImages() )` will fail_"

Comment: Your alternative is: a proper pimpl has the public object serving as a public interface to the object, ***and nothing more***. Full stop. There is never a reason for the implementation object to have any need to access its public instance. Try to figure out how to redesign your classes so that implementation objects have no need to have a reference to their public instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed some details, here is a setup that compiles.

```
#include <memory>

struct GAME_IMPL;
struct IMAGES {};

// A 'trick' I often use
// for pimpl you can define an abstract base
// helps you check if public and impl class
// implement the same functions
//
// it also ensures you only have a pointer to an interface
// of your implementation in your public header file

struct GAME_ITF
{
    virtual ~GAME_ITF() = default;
    virtual IMAGES get_Images() = 0;
protected:
    GAME_ITF() = default; // prevent accidental instantiation.
};


// in pimpl, game is just forwarding to game_impl
struct GAME : public GAME_ITF
{
    std::unique_ptr<GAME_ITF> _impl;

    GAME();
    virtual ~GAME() = default;

    IMAGES get_Images() override
    {
        return _impl->get_Images();
    }
};

struct SPRITE
{
    void load(IMAGES) { /*..*/ }
};

struct PLAYER
{
    SPRITE _sprite;

    explicit PLAYER(GAME_ITF& game)
    { 
        _sprite.load(game.get_Images());
    }
};

struct GAME_IMPL : public GAME_ITF
{
    IMAGES _images;
    PLAYER _player;

    GAME_IMPL() : 
        _player{*this} // <=== player can refer to the implementation's interface (no impl. details needed either)
    {
    }

    IMAGES get_Images() override
    {
        return IMAGES{};
    }
};

GAME::GAME() :
    _impl(std::make_unique<GAME_IMPL>())
{
}

int main()
{
    GAME game;
    IMAGES images = game.get_Images();
}
```

Comment: You can make `GAME_IMPL` [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final). It might allow compiler to devirtualize some call. (For `GAME`, it is most an OP's decision).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the cleanup :) I also could add some more explicit comments on what should go in what header file/source file if the OP so wishes.

Comment: I'm aware the original post didn't compile, it was just to show what was going on. Using a virtual interface seems quite clean and I can't imagine the vtable overhead is any worse than the dereferenceing overhead.

Comment: @cz and as jarod42 said, adding final to impl might optimize that vtable indirection away too

Answer (score 1):

P Kramer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69253885/3601660) is the good answer to the problem presented in my case.

However if someone ends up here via a Google search for the title alone *"Passing a partially constructed object"*, I did find that this is possible. Essentially the nested class (`GAME_IMPL` in this case) must assign its own pointer in the parent class (`GAME` in this case), i.e.

```
explicit GAME_IMPL( GAME& game ) : _player( (game._impl.reset( this ), game) ) { }
```

Now `GAME::_impl` is assigned during `PLAYER::PLAYER` and `GAME::getImages()` can be used.

This is messy for the pimpl case, but may solve similar issues.

Comment: +1 for a technically correct answer, but indeed don't use it :) The messiness is not only the syntax used in the constructor, but also in now having to know exactly how `GAME`, `GAME_IMPL` and `PLAYER` work to know if everything necessary for the construction of `_player` is correctly initialized.